# Format DateTime to DateTime with Milliseconds

Tags: csv, datetime, vbscript, timestamp, db2

I am pulling data from database into a recordset then converting to array and then writing to a CSV.

In the database all date values are stored as timestamps in this format.

```
2016-05-04 08:00:00.000000
```

But when I write to the CSV file the timestamp does not include the milliseconds.

Anyone know how to preserve the milliseconds?
Does the data in the recordset include the milliseconds?

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim sPassword
Dim sUserID
Dim sDefaultLib
Dim sSystem
Dim cs
Dim rc
Dim objIEDebugWindow

sDefaultLib =  *library*
sUserID = *userid*
sPassword = *password*
sSystem = *system*
cs = *connectionString*

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set data = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
con.Open cs, sUserID, sPassword
rc = con.State

If (rc = 1) Then
  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Library.Table FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY FOR READ ONLY WITH UR"
  data.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  data.Open strQuery, con
  Set filsSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim theYear
  Dim theMonth
  Dim theDay
  Dim mDate
  mDate = Date()
  theYear = DatePart("yyyy", mDate)
  theMonth = Right(String(2, "0") & DatePart("m", mDate), 2)
  theDate = Right(String(2, "0") & DatePart("d", mDate), 2)
  mDate = theYear & theMonth & theDate
  Set csvFile = filsSysObj.OpenTextFile("C:\SampleFile_" & mDate & ".csv", 8, True)

  columnCount = data.Fields.Count

  Set i = 0
  For Each field In data.Fields
    i= i + 1
    If (i <> columnCount) Then
      csvFile.Write Chr(34) & field.Name & Chr(34) & ","
    Else
      csvFile.Write Chr(34) & field.Name & Chr(34)
    End If
  Next
  csvFile.Write vbNewLine
End If

rowCount = data.RecordCount
row = 0

Dim row
Dim column
Dim resultsArray
Dim dateArray
resultsArray = data.GetRows

debug "hi"

i = 0
Do Until i>5
  MsgBox(i)
  i = i + 1
  'debug "in"
  'Dim value
  'Dim dArray()
  'debug "in"
  'value = Chr(34) & CStr(data.Fields(17).Value) & Chr(34) & ","

  'dArray = additem(dArray, value)
  'data.MoveNext
  'dateArray = dArray
Loop

debug "out"

For row = 0 To UBound(resultsArray, 2)
  For column = 0 To UBound(resultsArray, 1)
    If row = UBound(resultsArray, 2) And column = UBound(resultsArray, 1) Then
      csvFile.Write Chr(34) & resultsArray(column, row) & Chr(34)
    Else
      If column = 0 Then
        csvFile.Write Chr(34) & formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & Chr(34) & ","
      ElseIf column = 19 Then
        csvFile.Write Chr(34) & FormatDateTime(resultsArray(column, row),4) & Chr(34) & ","
      ElseIf column = 18 Then
        csvFile.Write Chr(34) & formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & Chr(34) & ","
      'ElseIf column = 17 Then
        'csvFile.Write Chr(34) & formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & Chr(34) & ","
      Else
        csvFile.Write Chr(34) & resultsArray(column, row) & Chr(34) & ","
      End If
    End If
  Next
  csvFile.Write vbNewLine
Next

csvFile.close

'----------------------Helper Functions are below-----------------------------
Sub Debug(myText)
  'Dim objIEDebugWindow must be defined globally
  'Call like this "Debug variableName"
  'Uncomment the next line to turn off debugging
  'Exit Sub

  If Not IsObject(objIEDebugWindow) Then
    Set objIEDebugWindow = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIEDebugWindow.Navigate "about:blank"
    objIEDebugWindow.Visible = True
    objIEDebugWindow.ToolBar = False
    objIEDebugWindow.Width   = 200
    objIEDebugWindow.Height  = 300
    objIEDebugWindow.Left    = 10
    objIEDebugWindow.Top     = 10
    Do While objIEDebugWindow.Busy
      WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    objIEDebugWindow.Document.Title = "IE Debug Window"
    objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<b>" & Now & "</b></br>"
  End If

  objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML = objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML & myText & "<br>" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Function formatDate(sDate)
  Dim theYear
  Dim theMonth
  Dim theDay
  Dim formattedDate

  theYear = Year(sDate)
  theMonth =  Right(String(2,"0") & DatePart("m", sDate),2)
  theDay = Right(String(2,"0") & DatePart("d", sDate),2)
  formattedDate = theYear & "-" & theMonth & "-" & theDate
  formatDate = formattedDate
End Function
```

The only field I am having issues with is field 17 of the recordset.
It is a timestamp datatype from a DB2 database.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to write to an array, just read from RS record by record and write to file, uses less memory. Treat the data as a string not as a date.

Comment: The reason i write to array is because i need to check for last value....(last row,column) so that i can not write a comma after that value.......can you explain how i would read the date into a variable as string?

Comment: Post your code and the datatypes of the field.

Comment: Code posted.....like you said another option would be to read it into the recordset as string but not really sure how to do that either. PS dont mind my debugging in there.

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve]. One issue is probably that the (commented) statement that would handle column 17 calls the function `formatDate`, which returns just the date.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers they obviously didn't write this that is glaringly obvious. If they had they would realise the difference between the `formatDate()` and `formatLongDateTime()` functions.

Comment: I dont even believe i have 300 lines of code up there. I did write most of it myself except for the Debug helper function. Though neither one of you were able to answer my question. Very helpful comments though thanks.......my issue is that when pulling into the recordset from the database the timestamp loses the millisecond and i am trying to figure out a way to preserve it. when i read the value out of the recordset which is directly from the DB it does not have the milseconds.

Comment: Well if you don't like the comments may be you should have a provided a [mcve] that way we wouldn't be picking your code apart. If you are saying the column from the `ADODB.Recordset` doesn't come back with milliseconds then give us that not a load of code that just complicates the question and adds ambiguity!

Comment: It's likely an issue with how DB2 returns the `TIMESTAMP` not ADODB. There is a lot of infromation about this - [Fun with dates and times](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html), [DB2 - TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampformat.html) and [DB2 - Connection string keywords - other properties](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordsotherprop.htm) *(especially the `DATETIMETOCHAR or ConvertDateTimeToChar` option)*.

Comment: I've never used DB2 but it took me all of 5 minutes to research it!

Comment: I doubt that date values are stored in any format. `2016-05-04 08:00:00.000000` is most likely just your local default output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the format is a timestamp in DB2 database. When i pull into a recordset it loses the milliseconds. My solution was to modify the query to add an extra row that pulls in only milliseconds and then later concatenate that back to the date. Please see below. Thanks for everyones help.

```
if(rc = 1) then
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": Database connection successful" & vbNewLine
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) &": Default Library: " & sDefaultLib & vbNewLine
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": Signed into server as: " & sUserID & vbNewLine
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": System: " & sSystem & vbNewLine
    strQuery = "SELECT ws_date, groupcd, userid, firstname, lastname, clientcd, unitcd, categorycd, category, activity, wrktype, subwrktype, step_begin, step_end, report_indicator, report_indicator, count, event_dattim, key_date, key_time, key_milsec, microsecond(event_dattim) FROM *Library.Name* FOR READ ONLY WITH UR"
    data.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    data.open strQuery, con
    if data.EOF then 
        logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": The query returned no data"
        logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": ---------------- The script DailyWorkstepReport.vbs file was abended at " & Now() &". There was no worksteps file created. ----------------" & vbNewLine
        logFile.close
    end if
    columnCount = data.Fields.Count
    columnCount = columnCount - 1

    Set filsSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set csvFile = filsSysObj.OpenTextFile("C:\VBScript\Dailys\" & fname, 8, True)

    set i = 0
    for each field in data.Fields
        i= i + 1
        if i < columnCount then
            csvFile.Write chr(34) & field.name & chr(34) & ","
        elseif i = columnCount then
            csvFile.Write chr(34) & field.name & chr(34)
        else
            exit for
        end if
    next
    csvFile.Write vbNewLine
else 
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": Database connection was unsuccessful. Database Connection Return Code: " & rc
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": ---------------- The script DailyWorkstepReport.vbs file was abended at " & Now() &". ----------------" & vbNewLine
    logFile.close
    csvfile.close
    wscript.quit
end if


dim row
dim column
dim resultsArray
resultsArray = data.GetRows

dim arrayRows
arrayRows = ubound(resultsArray, 2)

if  arrayRows <> 0 then 
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": " & (arrayRows + 1) & " rows were successfully read into the array for file " & fname & vbnewline


    for row = 0 to UBound(resultsArray, 2)
        for column = 0 to (UBound(resultsArray, 1) - 1)
            if row = Ubound(resultsArray, 2) and column = (ubound(resultsArray, 1) - 1) then
                csvFile.Write chr(34) & resultsArray(column, row) & chr(34)
            else
                if column = 0 then 
                    csvFile.Write chr(34) & formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & chr(34) & ","               
                elseif column = 19 then
                    csvFile.Write chr(34) & FormatDateTime(resultsArray(column, row),4) & chr(34) & ","
                elseif column = 18 then
                    csvFile.Write chr(34) & formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & chr(34) & ","
                elseif column = 17 then
                    Dim fDate
                    fDate = formatDate(resultsArray(column, row)) & " " & FormatDateTime(resultsArray(column, row),4) & ":" & second(resultsArray(column,row)) & "." & resultsArray((ubound(resultsArray, 1)), row)
                    csvFile.Write chr(34) & fDate & chr(34) & ","               
                else
                    csvFile.Write chr(34) & resultsArray(column, row) & chr(34) & ","               
                end if
            end if
        next 
        csvFile.Write vbNewLine
    next
    logfile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": " & (row) & " rows have been written to " & fname &vbNewLine
else
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": There was no data in the query results array for file " & fname & vbNewLine
    logFile.write FormatDateTime(Now(), 3) & ": ---------------- The script DailyWorkstepReport.vbs file was abended at " & Now() &". ----------------" & vbNewLine
    logfile.close
    csvfile.close
    wscript.quit
end if

csvFile.close
logfile.write "---------------- DailyWorkstepReport.vbs script successfully ended at " & Now() & "----------------" & vbNewLine
logfile.close
wscript.quit


REM ----------------------Helper Functions are below-----------------------------
Sub Debug( myText )
    'Dim objIEDebugWindow must be defined globally
    'Call like this "Debug variableName"
    'Uncomment the next line to turn off debugging
    'Exit Sub

    If Not IsObject( objIEDebugWindow ) Then
        Set objIEDebugWindow = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
        objIEDebugWindow.Navigate "about:blank"
        objIEDebugWindow.Visible = True
        objIEDebugWindow.ToolBar = False
        objIEDebugWindow.Width   = 200
        objIEDebugWindow.Height  = 300
        objIEDebugWindow.Left    = 10
        objIEDebugWindow.Top     = 10
        Do While objIEDebugWindow.Busy
            WScript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        objIEDebugWindow.Document.Title = "IE Debug Window"
        objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<b>" & Now & "</b></br>"
    End If

    objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML = objIEDebugWindow.Document.Body.InnerHTML & myText & "<br>" & vbCrLf
End Sub

function formatDate(sDate)  
    Dim theYear
    Dim theMonth
    Dim theDay
    Dim formattedDate

    theYear = Year(sDate)
    theMonth =  Right(String(2,"0") & DatePart("m", sDate),2)
    theDay = Right(String(2,"0") & DatePart("d", sDate),2)
    formattedDate = theYear & "-" & theMonth & "-" & theDate
    formatDate = formattedDate
end function
```